# Dynamic Chart Creation

Tags: software-development, charts, presentation

I am looking for a solution to build a dynamic Organizational Chart with pictures. The product/output would have to be easily readable by any person with a computer. This will be a file that will reside on SharePoint. The challenge is that it has to be one file.

Is there any solution for creating one interactive file, which does not need to be extracted, and that anyone can run on a computer that would render an experience somewhat similar to [basic primitives](http://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_local&view=local&Itemid=80&lang=en)?

I know most users have adobe reader, flash, java and PowerPoint or some presentation product, but is that it? Are there other programs that most people have and that could run a file that is interactive and easy to update, and which would display the same across all devices? And are there frameworks/templates I can use for this?

Comment: PDF is your best bet; however, you can also use dynamic HTML5 for a very portable presentation.

Comment: can you create interactivity within a PDF. If so, using what program?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what to suggest, because the goal is a bit vague. It would help to have a screenshot of the complexity of the document in mind, as OP's analogy to BasicPrimitives leaves a lot of room for variation.

With that in mind, if the demands were at the simple end, then a shared [StackEdit.io](https://stackedit.io/) document (essentially Markdown with some additional bells-and-whistles) might meet the need.

StackEdit includes support for:

- [UML diagrams](http://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/) -

[image: uml]

- and simple [flowcharts](http://adrai.github.io/flowchart.js/)

[image: flowchart]

It might be that this scenario does not allow for sufficient complexity, but it does meet these needs:

- single file
- shareable
- dynamic
- plus "publish" to (e.g.) Blogger, Wordpress, Tumblr, or "export" to HTML, PDF (if "sponsor"), etc.

On the other hand, it might be that this is too basic to meet the needs of OP.